# Can I connect 4 TTL communication devices to a single atmega 2560 RX pin?

Tags: ttl

I need to read 4 devices with one Rx pin on atmega2560. Devices are DS457 Motorola bar code readers. They communicate in inverted TTL at 9600 baud rate. I have already made signal inverter with 2 transistors and resistors.

[image]

My question is:

- Can I connect all 4 Tx of DS457 to single Rx pin without problems or do i need any diode for each reader?

**The readers will not work at the same time.** Only one at a time.

Comment: Not recommended. Try converting all four outputs of DS457 to Open drain. Having diodes in series with all four inputs will not help(Sink and source, Low and High). Inherently you will get inversion as Bonus

Comment: Thanks @Umar , was thinking the same, but for good its better to ask professionals :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are set on using that inverter circuit you could simply repeat the left hand transistor for each input (B C in parallel and emitters to each input).

Or just buy a 4-input NAND gate instead of trying to make one.

Comment: pff... where you were earlier? :)) it solves 2 problems at a time... i guess...

Comment: But NAND gate is not good for me i need NOR gate, because NAND will give `0` output when all 4 inputs are `1`. But you showed me the right way http://www.doctronics.co.uk/4002.htm

Comment: Okay- depends where the inversion needs to take place. If the input lines idle high then NAND, if low then NOR. Either way 1/2 a chip.

Comment: Yes idle is low on inverted ttl.